# Peut-on comparer l'emploi de « gourmand » dans « café gourmand » et « chronique gourmande » etc. ?

Tags: sens, synonymes, origine-ou-raison, académie-française, évolution-récente

À l'Académie française :

> Naguère était [*gourmand*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9G1099) qui aimait manger abondamment. Par métonymie,
>   on l’a employé comme adjectif avec des noms comme *bouche, lèvres,
>   regards, mines*, etc. pour former des expressions marquant un fort
>   désir de nourriture ou de plaisir charnel.
>
> Mais on observe depuis quelque temps un renversement dans les
>   expressions, puisque le gourmand n’est plus celui qui mange, mais ce
>   qui est mangé. On parle maintenant de *produits gourmands, de desserts
>   gourmands*, et de bien d’autres encore, quand il aurait suffi que ces
>   produits ou desserts soient pleins de goût ou savoureux. *Livre de
>   cuisine* semble alors une faute, qu’il faut combattre en employant,
>   évidemment, *livre gourmand*. On ne suivra pas cette mode et l’on
>   n’emploiera *gourmand* que pour qui aime les plaisirs de la table et de
>   la chair.
>
> ```
> on dit                                on ne dit pas
> De délicieuses pâtisseries            Des pâtisseries gourmandes
> Des fruits savoureux, appétissants    Des fruits gourmands
> Un café accompagné de mignardises     Un café gourmand
> ```
>
> [ Académie française, Dire, Ne pas dire • extensions de sens abusives, «
>   [gourmand](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/DNP0322) » ]

Au TLFi :

> [...] B. − 1. Qui aime la bonne nourriture et qui sait l'apprécier. [...] Rem. « *Gourmet* et *gourmand* ne sont pas interchangeables. Un gastronome
>   est un *gourmet*; un *gourmand* n'en est pas nécessairement un. On
>   peut être *gourmand* de chocolat et de sucreries et n'être en aucune
>   façon connaisseur pour les autres éléments qui constituent les
>   plaisirs de la table » (Dupré 1972).
>   ♦ [P. méton. du déterminé] Où l'on mange bien. *Région gourmande*. *Il
>   suffirait, à un gastronome, de dire que Saulieu, patrie gourmande de
>   l'illustre Alexandre Dumaine est en Morvan* (*Arts et loisirs*, 3 mai
>   1967, p. 75).
>
> [ [Trésor informatisé de la langue française, « [gourmand](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gourmand)] » ]

Au DHLF :

> Le mot a perdu sa connotation négative au XVIIIe et au XXe s.;
>   l'adjectif, dans des emplois extensifs, est devenu synonyme de
>   *gastronomique* (chronique gourmande, etc.).
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. Rey, chez
>   Robert, 2011, « gourmand » ]

Plus généralement : [Wiktionaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gourmand), [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gourmand), [Larousse en ligne 1](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/gourmand/37653?q=gourmande#37601), [Larousse en ligne 2](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/gourmand/37652?q=gourmande#37600), [Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9G1099).

---

- Peut-on comparer *chronique gourmande* et [*café gourmand*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/caf%C3%A9_gourmand) et
  expliquer s'ils s'appuient sur le même sens de l'adjectif *gourmand*
  ou autrement l'identifier pour chacun ?

  - Le propos de l'Académie vise-t-il l'emploi dans *chronique gourmande*
    ?
  - La remarque et ce qui la suit au TLF aident-ils à comprendre
    davantage et si oui comment ; *région gourmande* est-il comme le premier ou le deuxième ?

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas bien certain de bien comprendre la première question, pourrais-tu la reformuler plus clairement ? Selon tes exemples, les deux adjectifs n'ont pas le même sens : "chronique gourmande" est vue comme "gastronomique", c'est-à-dire "de gourmet", alors qu'un "café gourmand" est un café pour les gourmands, qui veulent des choses sucrées à grignoter avec leur café.

Pour ta deuxième question, oui, elle vise l'emploi de "chronique gourmande" vu que celui-ci est déjà une utilisation impropre de "gourmand" selon les propres termes de l'Académie. Elle respecterait les critères s'il s'agissait d'une chronique de gens qui mangent beaucoup ou qui aiment manger sans distinction de qualité.

Aparté : dans le texte de l'Académie, l'ellipse logique du "livre de cuisine" sort de nulle part et ne semble pas avoir beaucoup de sens. En quoi "livre de cuisine" devrait-il être remplacé par "livre gourmand" ? Cela ne renvoie à aucune constatation établie avant dans le texte, même en tant qu'extrapolation.

Concernant la troisième question, "région gourmande" est quelque peu équivoque. La définition et l'exemple semblent auguiller vers "gourmet", "gastronomique" ("où l'on mange bien", "à un gastronome"), mais même cela n'est pas complètement acquis. Personnellement, je pourrais très bien dire "on mange bien dans cette région" dans le sens de "les repas sont copieux", mais sans nécessairement faire allusion au raffinement ou à la qualité de la nourriture. Se pose aussi la question de savoir ce qu'est une "région où on mange bien". En France en tout cas, il n'y a pas de région où l'on mange "mal", que ce soit en quantité ou en qualité. Le manger mal est le fait de la personne, de sa richesse financière et des produits qu'il achète. Cela nous pousserait donc à comprendre "région gourmande" à l'aune de la prépondérance de la cuisine dans l'image qu'on a de la région. Par exemple, la Bretagne et la Normandie pourraient être vues comme gourmandes à cause de la culture de la crème, du beurre et des pommes, alors que la Champagne n'est pas une région gourmande car on n'y rattache aucune vraie idée de mets typique.

En conclusion, je dirais que l'adjectif "gourmand" est le cas typique d'un adjectif qui se module selon le locuteur et le destinataire car son sens est nébuleux. Le contexte aidera à préciser le sens.